# how to remove the top navigation bar or header top on wordpress website?

Tags: menus, navigation, code

My website (bargainbosss.com) all of a sudden started displaying a navigation bar at the top of the website. I don't have that menu option checked, only a primary menu. I can't figure out how to remove this bar and it's driving me crazy. I just want the primary menu--the one underneath my logo. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can remove this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add more detail? What theme are you using? Do you have any widgets turn on? Have you recently added or updated your plugins or theme?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the author didn't include the check for menu items before calling the top nav bar.

Two methods:

1. Dashboard --> appearance --> customize --> Additional CSS add the following piece of code and save changes:

   ```
   #topnav {
     display:none;
   }
   ```
2. [Create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/%20%20WP%20Child%20theme) and include this page `neville\template-parts\partials\headers\header-tmpl-default.php`. Make sure to remove the below line from the page you included in the child theme:

   ```
   add_action( 'neville__header_default', neville__header_default_top_nav',      20 );
   ```

Either one should work. However, I'd recommend the second method. Its always better to have a child theme while making changes to any theme.